# What's wrong with comparing BufferedImages?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final BufferedImage data = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
    {//all images include alpha
        final Graphics2D g2d = data.createGraphics();
        final BufferedImage img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("z:\\img1.png"));
        g2d.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, null);
        final BufferedImage img2 = ImageIO.read(new File("z:\\img2.png"));
        g2d.drawImage(img2, 100, 100, null);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    final File fa = new File("z:\\a\\test.png");
    ImageIO.write(data, "png", fa);
    final BufferedImage newData = ImageIO.read(fa);

    final File fb = new File("z:\\b\\test.png");
    ImageIO.write(newData, "png", fb);
    final BufferedImage newData2 = ImageIO.read(fb);

    System.out.println(equal(data, data));          // true
    System.out.println(equal(data, newData));       // false
    System.out.println(equal(newData, newData2));   // true
}

public static boolean equal(final BufferedImage img1, final BufferedImage img2) {
    final int width = img1.getWidth();
    final int height = img1.getHeight();
    if (width == img2.getWidth() && height == img2.getHeight()) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                final int argb1 = img1.getRGB(x, y);
                final int argb2 = img2.getRGB(x, y);
                if (argb1 != argb2){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I try to verify image consistency, but the result, why equal return false between data and newData??? How should i correct the code?

By the way, it seems ImageIO.write had a suspicious issue. 
I had writed some images by ImageIO.write, PngEncoderB(http://catcode.com/pngencoder/), PngEncoder(http://objectplanet.com/pngencoder/) and image4j(https://github.com/imcdonagh/image4j).
PngEncoderB's, PngEncoder's and image4j's are the same image pixels, only ImageIO.write's different. Actually i don't know which one is correct. If you're interested, please use image compare software like beyond compare / DiffImg, to check the alpha.

Comment: I need to do a few checks, but PNG does not support premultiplied alpha. Since the BufferedImage you're building does use premultiplied alpha, that means that it needs to be converted to normal ARGB, when writing as PNG, and when getting pixels with getRGB(). However, getRGB() by very definition, converts pixels one at a time, doing its best to convert the pixel from its natural format to RGB. It is very unlikely that converting an entire image would do the same, rather pixels would be converted as a lot, in context. Giving out slightly different results than converting one by one.

Comment: In my program, i used the VolatileImage(Transparency.TRANSLUCENT) draw some images, getSnapshot() and write as PNG. In the same way only pre-alpha BufferedImage write out as same as it. Is "PNG does not support premultiplied alpha" the image standard? Or API only? It's there any way to convert pre-ARGB to normal ARGB losslessly? @kumesana